# jQuery - Toggle attribute's value?

Tags: jquery

So I'm creating a cost calculator in jQuery and PHP. I use the following snippet to toggle a button, so user will see what is checked.

```
$("[data-button='5']").click(function(){
        $("[data-button='5'] .status").attr("src" , "hintalaskurikuvat/greenstatus.png");
        $("[data-button='5']").toggleClass("selected");

        });
```

But however, it won't toggle the image, I know that. Is there a simple way to toggle between
`hintalaskurikuvat/greenstatus.png` and `hintalaskurikuvat/redstatus.png` as the src for `[data-button='5']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this could work for you

```
var image;
if ($("[data-button='5']").hasClass("selected"))
    image = "hintalaskurikuvat/greenstatus.png";   
else
    image = "hintalaskurikuvat/redstatus.png";

$("[data-button='5'] .status").attr("src" , image);
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is what I did to have it available as an extension of JQuery (just add this to your *.js file):

```
(function($) {

$.fn.toggleAttr = function(attribute, value) {
/// <summary>
///     Toggles on/off provided attribute for any tag/element 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="attribute" type="object">
///    Name of attribute to add or remove, eg: checked=""
/// </param> 
/// <param name="value" type="object">
///    Value of the attribute to add or remove, eg: ="checked"
/// </param> 
    if($(this).attr(attribute)){
        $(this).removeAttr(attribute,value);
    }
    else{
        $(this).attr(attribute,value);
    } 
};
})(jQuery);
```

and simple way of using it:

```
$('.someclass').toggleAttr('checked', 'checked');
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
var sel = $("[data-button='5']");
sel.find('.status').attr("src", sel.hasClass('selected') ? "greenstatus.png" : "redstatus.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your click function:

```
$("[data-button='5']").attr("src", ($("[data-button='5']").attr("src")=="hintalaskurikuvat/greenstatus.png") ? "hintalaskurikuvat/redstatus.png":"hintalaskurikuvat/greenstatus.png" );
```

Comment: Hmmm, works fine when I test it. Perhaps you didn't implement the code as it needs to be.

Comment: I just added it after the click event?

Comment: OK, there were a few things wrong with the fiddle you posted but I corrected them here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/JLg7t/1/.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("[data-button='5']").click(function(){
    var $img = $(".status", this);
    var cur = $img.attr("src");
    var fst = 'hintalaskurikuvat/greenstatus.png';
    var scd = 'hintalaskurikuvat/redstatus.png';
    $img.attr('src', cur == fst ? scd : fst);
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});
```

Comment: Works, but I like the way with less lines ;)